# Triangle *number* pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing patterns in python but i can't seem to get a this pattern to change.

```
number = int(input("Enter number of rows to display the arithmetic pyramid: ")) 

for row in range(0,number):
    number = number +1
    for col in range(1,row+1):
        print(col,end="")
    print()
```

This outputs:

1 
12 
123 
1234

I Need:

```
     1
    12
   123
  1234
 12345
```

Please also help that when user input's 5 it displays 1-5

Thanks in advance

Comment: `print('\n'.join([''.join(map(str,range(1,i))).rjust(5)for i in range(2,7)]))`

Comment: @sheldore not actualy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.rjust`

**Ex:**

```
number = int(input("Enter number of rows to display the arithmetic pyramid: ")) 
val = ""
for row in range(1,number+1):
    val += str(row)
    print(str(val).rjust(number))
```

**Output:**

```
    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh I appreciate it